# Why is initial drag position incorrect when using a scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a slider. It should allow to drag an element along a horizontal axis and get the corresponding integer value. I had no problem doing this until I introduced a scale.

This is the fiddle. The incorrect behaviour can be seen as soon as we start dragging. After that it appears to work correcly.

```js
slider.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', r)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return scale(d.x); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y })
    .call(drag)

function dragmove(d) {
    var x = Math.max(r, Math.min(w - r, d3.event.x)),
        numberNow = scale.invert(x)
    slider.attr("cx", d.x = x)
    d3.select('#value').text(numberNow)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hanbzu/NkStD/

How can I prevent the initial incorrect behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the initial behaviour without changing the 'data' I provide through d3. I've used the `origin` method as follows:

```js
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function() { 
    var t = d3.select(this)
    return { x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy") }
  })
  .on('drag', dragmove);
```

See the [updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hanbzu/NkStD/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Have no clue on `d3.js`, but I notice that by changing this:

```
slider.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', r)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x;    /* scale.invert(d.x) */ })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; }) // problem? --^
    .call(drag);
```

it drags OK from the get-go. But the initial value is wrong.

By setting number to:

```
var number = 400 / 100 * 50;
// I scaled down width to 400
```

Start position is OK, but there is probably a better way to solve that one.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/NkStD/2/)

#### Edit:

Set it like this. (And also include the removal of `scale.invert(d.x)` as mentioned above):

```
var number = 50;

var slider = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data([{ x: scale(number), y: h / 2 }]);
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/NkStD/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not scaling the value you're setting:

```
slider.attr("cx", d.x = x)
```

You're passing in plain `d.x` instead of `scale(d.x)` that you've used to set the value initially. Solved by scaling both values:

```
slider.attr("cx", scale(d.x = x))
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NkStD/3/).

Comment: But by doing it that way, the circle doesn't drag with the cursor. It moves faster.